# Passing an object's string value to component using a button Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, button, components, routerlink

In my html template of my component 'a', I have a button which is used to navigate to an other component :

```
<button nbButton status="info" class="left" [routerLink]="['/centers', center.id, 'prices']">PRICES</button>
```

So clicking on this button made me move to an other component 'b'.

In the component 'a' I have a private object variable, which contains a string value `currenciesAccepted`, basically :`myObject.currenciesAccepted`.

In the component 'b', I need this string value, so I need to pass it when I click on the button, to navigate from the component 'a' to the component 'b'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<button nbButton status="info" class="left" 
[routerLink]="['/centers', center.id, 'prices']" 
[queryParams]='{currenciesAccepted: myObject.currenciesAccepted}' >PRICES</button>
```

in centers component

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

currenciesAccepted: any = {};
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe( params => {
     this.currenciesAccepted  = params.get('currenciesAccepted') ;
     })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[queryParams]='{"obj":myObject.currenciesAccepted}'` to the button, this will pass the string in query params

Comment: Ok, but how to get this obj on the component 'b' ?

Comment: The ActivatedRoute Observable contains the query parameters. You can't access a private variable from the template though, so either switch it to public or create a getter method.